# C global variable compilation error with -D flag: expected identifier or '('

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, global-variables

I have a basic C file. It compiles and runs perfectly fine with the following prompt:

```
gcc program.c -D N=100 -O4 -Ofast
```

However, when I add a -D flag for a second variable (z):

```
gcc program.c -D N=100 -D z=2 -O4 -Ofast
```

I get the following error:

```
program.c:14:5: error: expected identifier or '('
int z = 2;
    ^
<command line>:2:11: note: expanded from here
#define z 2
          ^
1 error generated.
```

The program.c code is below:

```
#include "program.h"
#include <stdio.h>

double A[N][N];
double B[N][N];
int z;


int min(int x, int y){
    return (x < y) ? x : y;
}

void standard() {
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i < N; i++)
        for (j=0; j < N; j++)
            A[i][j] += B[j][i];
}

void tiling() {
    int i,j,x,y;
    for (i=0; i < N; i+=z)
        for (j=0; j < N; j+=z)
            for (x=i; x < min((i + z),N); x++)
                 for (y=j; y < min((j + z),N); y++)
                     A[x][y] += B[y][x];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    printf("The number is: %d. The next number is: %d", N, z);
    printf("The min is: %d.", min(13,20));
    B[40][50] = 21.0;
    tiling();
    //standard();
    printf("The matrix is: %f.",A[50][40]);
    return 0;
}
```

It's been awhile since I have coded in C so I am rusty and stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, macros have been around for a while in C and their semantics have not changed that much. So you should be able to tell the difference between a macro and a variable.

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `#define`ing `z` to become `2` the preprocessor changes

```
int z;
```

to

```
int 2;
```

which you probably do not want.

Same for all other occurrences of `z`.

What you might want is to change

```
int z;
```

to be

```
int z = Z;
```

and use

```
-D Z=2
```

instead of

```
-D z=2
```

For your further reading: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/

Comment: Thank you for the quick and very comprehensive answer! That fixed my problem...I see now that I was misunderstanding the -D flag.